# Can not install Java

Tags: installation, java

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ferramroberto/java
```

After this command I am getting error:

```
Error reading https://launchpad.net/api/1.0/~ferramroberto/+archive/java: Couldn't resolve host 'launchpad.net
```

Comment: What's your output for `ping launchpad.net`?

Comment: ppa:ferramroberto - in not a good repository

Answer (score 1):

1. To add our PPA and install the latest Oracle Java (JDK) 7 in Ubuntu, use the commands below:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java

   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install oracle-jdk7-installer
   ```
2. After the installation you have enable the jdk:

   ```
   update-alternatives –display java
   ```
3. Check if Ubuntu uses Java JDK 7

   ```
   java -version
   ```

   The correct answer should be like this:

   ```
   javac 1.7.0_07
   ```
4. Adding JAVA_HOME to environment

   Edit the file `/etc/environment` and add `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle` to the end of the file.

   First open a Terminal (Applications → Accessories → Terminal), then enter:

   ```
   sudo gedit /etc/environment
   ```